# For human annotation projects, what are some commonly used metrics to assess grader reliability?

Tags: classification, dataset, rating

Lots of machine learning datasets are now created by having human raters annotate and provide labels to questions. Usually, a gold set is the most robust way of seeing if the raters are doing a good job. I am wondering what are some metrics commonly used for understanding how well a rater is doing?

Comment: Do you want to assess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability or do you want to assess how closely each of the raters' ratings correspond to the "gold set" of ratings?

Comment: I would like to ultimately assess how closely each of the raters' ratings correspond to the "gold set", but when a gold set is not available.

Comment: You can’t get something for nothing—there’s no free lunch. You can either make some assumptions about what the gold looks like, then measure relative to that (_quality estimation_), or acquire actual gold data.

Comment: Make multiple raters annotate/rate the same items, and use the methods of [tag:agreement-statistics]. Consider adding that tag!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of a gold standard or criterion variable, you can assess inter-rater reliability by computing the intraclass correlation (ICC). The ICC decomposes variance in the ratings that is due to differences between raters and differences between ratees (the questions, in this case).

To follow-up on the comment of Arya McCarthy above (you can’t get something for nothing): This approach would, more or less, take the average rating per question as the 'gold standard'.

If each question was rated by the same set of raters, you can estimate ICCs using function `icc` from R package `irr`. If (some) questions were rated by different sets (and numbers) of raters, it is probably more convenient to use function `lmer` from R package lme4 to compute ICCs.